# double json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why this double json response are not successful:

```
[{"first_content":"content",...}][{"second_content":"content",...}]
```

So i am getting the message `Oops! Try Again`.

```
if(isset($_GET['start'])) {
    echo get_posts($db, $_GET['start'], $_GET['desiredPosts']);
    echo get_posts1($db, $_GET['start'], $_GET['desiredPosts']);
    $_SESSION['posts_start']+= $_GET['desiredPosts'];
    die();
}


var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;
var loadMore = $('#load-more');

loadMore.click(function () {
                loadMore.addClass('activate').text('Loading...');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'profile.php',
                    data: {
                        'start': start,
                        'desiredPosts': desiredPosts
                    },
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (responseJSON, responseJSON1) {
                        alert(responseJSON);
                        loadMore.text('Load More');
                        start += desiredPosts;
                        postHandler(responseJSON, responseJSON1);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        loadMore.text('Oops! Try Again.');
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        loadMore.removeClass('activate');
                    }
                });
            });
```

What is the solution to get a double json response ? With one  there is no problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Double JSON response" as you call them is basically invalid JSON. You should have something like so:

```
{"first_content":"content", "second_content":"content",...}
```

Or as a couple of people mentioned:

```
[{"first_content":"content",...}, {"second_content":"content",...}]
```

You probably need to modify some server side code, your get_posts function could return a PHP array instead of a JSON array. Example:

```
function get_posts(){
    $array = array('content' => 'foo', 'title' => 'bar');
    return $array;
}
```

Then in your profile.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['start'])) {
    $posts = get_posts($db, $_GET['start'], $_GET['desiredPosts']);
    $posts1 = get_posts1($db, $_GET['start'], $_GET['desiredPosts']);
    echo array($posts, $posts1);
    $_SESSION['posts_start']+= $_GET['desiredPosts'];
    die();
}
```

Comment: or wrap the arrays in a object

Comment: rather should be [{"first_content":"content",...},{"second_content":"content",...}]

Comment: The json content are from two independently queries.

Comment: Are you the one generating the JSON with a server side code? Could we see the code?

Comment: Ohh I see what you're doing, you're using get_posts to output a JSON array. Personally, I'd make get_posts generate PHP arrays, then merge the 2 of them with array_merge and then use json_encode on the merged array.

Comment: no, i always need two independetly json responses because the  postHandler(responseJSON, responseJSON1); should have two objects

Comment: Well, you can use responseJSON[0] and responseJSON[1] to send to postHandler.